# Find out last 2 years old files in Ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu

We have more than 4 years of data in our system. We need to move 2 years old files and directories in a new repository. Our requirement is needed to list files and folders 1.Jan 2017 to as of now 2.Exclude files end with .html and .xml I tried to find command but couldn't work out. So guys if any shell script really helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Usually it is helpful to include in your question what exactly did you already try. By the way, since you need files from 1.1.2017, you can use 'ls' with 'grep' and filter just by the year (2017, 2018, 2019). 'grep' can help with exclusion too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
touch -t 201701010000 test
find / \( -type f -o -type d \) -anewer test \( ! -name "*.html" -a ! -name "*.xml" \) -print
```

This will give you all the files and folders newer than 2017 01 01 00:00 (First of January 2017 00:00)

If you want to move them, you can replace -print with -exec together with move command